# how to use right/left to split a variable in sqldf, as in left(x,n)

Tags: r, sqldf

Is there a different function in R to use to get the same result as in SQL for left or right function?

For instance, the following query in SQL would give the first 6 characters of a column:

```
select left(x, 6)
from table
```

However, when I try this in sqldf like this:

```
sqldf("select left(x,6) from table")
```

I get the following error:

> Error in sqliteSendQuery(con, statement, bind.data) :
>
> error in statement: near "(": syntax error

It gives me the x variable but not left(x,6). To clarify, the length of x is more than 6.

Comment: I suspect that this means that the `left` function is not implemented in `sqldf`

Comment: The function is named `leftstr`, not `left`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `sqldf`, the function is named `leftstr`, not `left`. (answer by G.Grothendieck in the comment)

Comment: Note that you can find `leftstr` and the other additional SQLite functions that are available here:  `library(RSQLite); help("initExtension")` .